# how to combine the all values of keys which is inside an object to a new array in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the dynamic data coming in this format, i want to turn into and array based on the toolset object keys, but toolset object have not constant number of keys

```
{ toolset:{
   info1:{
      event-date:{},
      event-time:{},
     },

info2:{
      event-location:{},
      event-url:{},
     }

}}
```

i want it like this

```
inputs=[{event-date:{}},{event-time:{}},{event-location:{}},{event-url:{}}]
```

with the minimal code in javascript es6

Comment: so, you just want to merge each property of toolset object into a flat array?

Comment: @Ja͢ck yes i already mentioned in question how i want result

Comment: but `info2` isn't even part of `toolset`?

Comment: There is no such a thing like `[{{}, {}},...]`, do you mean `[[{}, {},...],...]` ?

Comment: An array of single-property objects is very hard to work with. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: This code is broken, please update question with code block that works. Please use https://www.jslint.com/ to confirm the code is valid JavaScript before submitting a question.

Comment: i updated , please take your vote back

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`, `flat` and `Object.entries` methods to return flat array of objects.

```js
const data = {
  toolset: {
    info1: {
      'event-date': {},
      'event-time': {},
    },
    info2: {
      'event-location': {},
      'event-url': {},
    }
  },
}

const inputs = Object
  .values(data.toolset)
  .map(Object.entries)
  .flat()
  .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))


console.log(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let obj = {
  toolset: {
    info1: {
      "event-date": {},
      "event-time": {}
    },

    info2: {
      "event-location": {},
      "event-url": {}
    }
  }
};

let finalArray = [];

Object.values(obj.toolset).forEach(obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => finalArray.push({ [key]: val }));
});

console.log(finalArray); // <==  your desired array
```